# Prediction using wide and deep learning network in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've trained a wide and deep learning network on my dataset containing attributes - product_id, views, likes, dislikes, shares, user_ratings. user_ratings is taken as target variable. I am able to evaluate my model based on test set I've provided. But I am not able to understand how can I generate predictions. I've used "predict" method as follows, but all I am getting is [1] :

```
model.predict(input_fn=lambda : input_fn(df_train[:1]),as_iterable=False)
```

where input_fn is :

```
def input_fn(df):
  continuous_cols = {k: tf.constant(df[k].values) for k in CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS}
  categorical_cols = {
  k: tf.SparseTensor(
      indices=[[i, 0] for i in range(df[k].size)],
      values=df[k].values,
      dense_shape=[df[k].size, 1])
  for k in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS}
  feature_cols = dict(continuous_cols)
  feature_cols.update(categorical_cols)
  product_name = tf.constant(df[TARGET_COLUMN].values)
  return feature_cols, product_name
```

Also, in df_train[:1], I am giving user_rating value. But when I try to drop this column and execute it, its showing an error. The problem is the model is working on binary classification problem but I want to use 10 categories for user ratings ( 1 to 10 ).

How can I achieve this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my issue by passing -> n_classes=10 parameter to the model.